# Self-Perceived Quality of Life based on operation success chance

Tags: cognitive-psychology, measurement, self

I heard about this method in a psychology lecture once: let's say that a person has some sort of chronic illness, and they are offered an operation to cure them. Then, the patient is asked about what the minimum chance of success of the operation is, such that they would agree to undergo it. For instance, a patient for whom there is a 99% chance of success of the operation will probably have a higher quality of life while having his/her illness than a patient that only has a 30% chance of success of the operation.

What is this scale of happiness of ill patients called?